# Variable has different values when used in separate label texts

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to make a program that has a timer and a label that displays your previous times. I use the same variable (result) to display the timer's text and the time list's text, but there is sometimes a 0.01 or 0.02 difference between the two.

I've tried saving the result variable to another variable, then changing the timer_label text to the new variable at the same time as the list_label, but this has failed to even update the text on the timer_label
at all. timer_label.update() and root.update_idletasks() has also not solved the issue.

```
def timer_start():
    global begin_time, timer_allow
    timer_allow = True
    # Allows refresh loop to occur
    begin_time = time.time()
    # Stores time of timer start
    refresher()
    # Calls refresh loop


def refresher():
    global begin_time, timer_allow, result
    cur = time.time()
    # Stores the current time
    result = round(cur - begin_time, 2)
    # Calculates and displays time since timer start
    timer_label.config(text=result)
    # Updates timer text
    if timer_allow:
        root.after(10, refresher)
        # Loops the refresher function every hundredth of a second


def timer_end():
    global timer_allow, result, num1, num2, num3, time_list
    timer_allow = False
    # Stops the refresher loop
    num3 = num2
    num2 = num1
    num1 = result
    time_list = (str(num1) + "  " + str(num2) + "  " + str(num3))
    # Creates the string for the times list
    list_label.config(text=time_list)
    # Updates the times list
```

After the timer is stopped, the timer and the list of times should display the same time, but sometimes the times are 0.01 or 0.02 off.

Comment: If you have a `global` statement it is already a good indicator that your code need a revision. Use function arguments and return values instead, or implement your timer as a class.

Comment: Yeah, I will work on changing the global variables to function arguments, I'm a newbie to python. Thank you for the advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I ran your code and the first problem that came up was this

```
NameError: name 'num2' is not defined
```

Inside timer_end(), I believe that instead of:

```
num3 = num2
num2 = num1
num1 = result
```

you might wanna have this:

```
num1 = result
num2 = num1
num3 = num2
```

as the first time that timer_end() is called, num2 has not been initialized. Furthermore, even if you have initialized all 3 of them beforehand, only num1 would be changed in the tkinter window.

As for your main question, I think the difference of 0.01 is appearing because after you set timer_allow to False (inside timer_end()), refresher() is being called yet again for the last time (refresher() only finds out that timer_allow is false after running the line:

```
timer_label.config(text=result)
```

). This means that result gets updated once AGAIN in the tkinter window, AFTER timer_allow has been set to False. To correct this you can try something like:

```
def refresher():
    global begin_time, timer_allow, result
    cur = time.time()
    # Stores the current time
    result = round(cur - begin_time, 2)
    # Calculates and displays time since timer start
    if timer_allow:
        timer_label.config(text=result)
        # Updates timer text
        root.after(10, refresher)
        # Loops the refresher function every hundredth of a second
```

This seems to work for me and the difference of 0.01 is gone as far as I can tell.

Oh and just like Klaus D. mentioned above, avoiding global variables and using arguments/parameters, objects and the like is a better approach to use in general.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I'm new to python (and coding in general), so it's my bad for using global variables without fully understanding what their use was.